# Mac/Windows Cross Platform Console app using Xamarian Studio Community Edition

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono, cairo

So, I am running the Community build of Xamarian Studio on my Mac, and building a very simple console application that takes a CSV file as input and uses Cairo to generate some PNG images from the data. So, tried to build this on the Mac, and then run the result on a windows platform, but I get an error that reads:

Unhanded exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type "Cairo.TextExtents" from assembly "Mono.Cairo.dll, version 4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='0738eb9f132ed756' because the method 'get_XBearing' has no implementation (no RVA)

The Mono.Cairo.dll is in the same folder as the executable.

So, the question is this: Can I build a console app on the Mac, and run the result on Windows, and if so, what am I doing wrong?